# How to extract elements from lists in column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, mapping

I want to extract the type, month and year of the email campaign. Values in `campaign` column is string. I applied the split method and then try to use mapping function to extract the info to different columns. I don't know why the mapping failed for the `campaign_month` extraction.

```py
emailClick_df['campaign_info'] = emailClick_df['campaign'].str.split('-')
emailClick_df['campaign_type'] = emailClick_df['campaign_info'].map(lambda x:x[0])
emailClick_df['campaign_month'] = emailClick_df['campaign_info'].map(lambda x:x[1])
emailClick_df['campaign_year'] = emailClick_df['campaign_info'].map(lambda x:x[2])
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZwKU.png)
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9ZNL.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split with `expand` parameter and then set all three columns in one go:

```
df[['campaign_type', 'campaign_month', 'campaign_year']] = \
    df['campaign'].str.split('-', expand=True)

df
```

Output:

```
              campaign campaign_type campaign_month campaign_year
0  Standard-Mar19-2020      Standard          Mar19          2020
```

P.S. Your error indicates that most likely some `campaign_info` values were not in the form `type-month-year` and were therefore not split into a list of multiple strings, so the attempt to get second value in the list fails. Otherwise your approach should have been fine as well. You can find those problematic records with

```
df[df['campaign'].str.split('-').str.len() != 3]
```

Comment: Hi Perl, thanks for your quick response! I did check that some `campaign_info` values are not in the form `type-month-year`. Your answer is quite helpful!